# Fail execute goal Maven

Tags: java, maven

I try to execute Hello World in Maven but is not work when I execute `mvn compile`:

My source:

> https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

My error with maven:

> https://pastebin.com/Qamd6Jk5

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.0</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <transformers>
                        <transformer
                          implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                          <mainClass>hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                      </transformers>
                      <source>9</source>
                      <target>9</target>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My File:

Greeter.java:

```
package hello;

public class Greeter {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package hello;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        System.out.println(greeter.sayHello());
    }
}
```

Edit:

My java version:

```
openjdk 9
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

My Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (NON-CANONICAL_2017-04-10T13:56:20+03:00_root; 2017-04-10T12:56:20+02:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.13.7-1-arch", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I try to change pom.xml but it is the same result...

I don't know why I have a error ?

Comment: Do you use the shade plugin on purpose? You don't need it for a hello world application...

Comment: The Maven error message tells you there is a compilation failure. There should be more error messages - you should be seeing what exactly the compilation error is as well. What is the compilation error?

Comment: @assylias i try to remove plugin but is the same

Comment: @Jesper i update my post with all error in pastbin

Comment: One difference between your `pom.xml` and the one in the Spring tutorial is that you specified `<source>9</source>` and `<target>9</target>` while this is not in the Spring tutorial.

Comment: @Jesper beacause is my version of java: 9 i added for try to fix my error

Comment: Are you sure that the version of Maven and the Maven compiler plugin / Maven shade plugin that you are using understands this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to setup your maven compiler by adding this inside your `<plugins>` section

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.9</source>
            <target>1.9</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: sorry i don't show you my version of Java but I edit my poste

Comment: Thanks, it's work, but why is "1.9" instead of 9, and why maven-compiler-plugin instead of maven-shade-plugin.

Comment: It's because that's how maven compiler uses it to identify java version numbering, it's not following the oracle standards about it, and the maven shade should be used when you're "packaging" your app, but that is AFTER compilation, Shade takes care of packaging but previously maven-compiler does the compilation